# How to import key hash to my android app?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-keystore, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

I generate key hash by these commands

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore xxx.keystore -alias xxx -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

keytool -exportcert -alias xxx -keystore xxx.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Then I got this key hash

```
Bmce+9aHdOoVtE7fS3B07tfj7Bc=
```

I add it to intellij Artifacts

[image: artifacts]

But, when I use facebook sdk to login, I got this message.

```
Invalid key hash, The key hash 0FltZY3_r2cu8z_LOYILzjwSxjA does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at http://developer.faceboo.......
```

Why the key is still not correct?

Comment: have u configure your app in facebook developer console ?

Comment: When you genrate this key : Bmce+9aHdOoVtE7fS3B07tfj7Bc= is ask you password after run this command keytool -exportcert ?

Comment: Check : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_facebook_integration.htm

Comment: After I run first command, it ask me keystore password, I use xxxxxx as password, and then I input these option "Is CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown correct?  [no]:  yes", and then it ask me "Enter key password for <xxx> (RETURN if same as keystore password):", Then I press enter, because the password also xxxxxx. After that, I run second command, it ask me "Enter keystore password:", I input xxxxxx, then I got Bmce+9aHdOoVtE7fS3B07tfj7Bc=